# Can't find the source of some "asm", "generated" header files in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, c, source, x86, linux-headers

So, I am writing a module, that is working in kernel space.
My code compiles correctly and works correctly.

The thing is that there are some header files, which I couldn't find anywhere.
That doesn't make sense to me, how come everything goes right when header files are not present.
They must be present somewhere.

These are some of header files I couldn't find anywhere
(there are more, but for my question, they may be enough):

```c
#include <asm/errno.h>
#include <asm/socket.h>  /* /include/linux/socket.h */
#include <stdarg.h>      /* /include/linux/kernel.h */
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <asm/mmiowb.h>  /* /include/linux/spinlock.h */
#include <asm/param.h>   /* /include/linux/jiffies.h */
```

Though some of header files can be found on architectures other than `x86`,
but I don't think that's any solution to the question.

And I don't have any idea where to look for these files:

```c
#include <generated/timeconst.h>    /* /include/linux/jiffies.h */
#include <generated/bounds.h>
#include <generated/autoconf.h>     /* /include/linux/kconfig.h */
#include <generated/asm-offsets.h>
```

I am looking for these files in the following directories from [linux kernel 5.4.31](https://www.kernel.org/):

```
/include
/include/uapi
/arch/x86/include
/arch/x86/include/uapi
```

I expect the files to be found in the above include paths. 
But I don't know much about where and how linux header files are processed after compilation, 
since I'm finding for them in the source code.

Comment: What command do you use to compile your module? After you have compiled your module can you run `grep asm/errno.h $(find , -name \*.d)` to locate your first include file using the information the compiler has written?

Comment: @icarus I am using ``make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` `` to build the module. Though, I am not understanding the command you're saying, it just runs with a line printing `find ',': No such file or directory` and doesn't exit.

Comment: @icarus you can try to run this `make` command in `/net/wireless/` directory. It has a file `nl80211.c` (which has a header file `#include <linux/err.h>`) which I am using as a reference to write my code.

Comment: Sorry, typo, `grep linux/err.h $(find . -name \*.d)`  The idea is that after you have done the build in addition to the ".ko" file you will have one or more ".o" object files and also one or more ".d" files. The latter are Makefile fragments listing dependencies.

Comment: @icarus There is no `.d` file in my directory after the build, all I have are `.ko`, `.o`, `.mod.c`, `.mod.o`, `modules.order`, `Module.symvers`, files other than `.c` and `.h` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ll find the header files used by your build in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/`, see for example

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/ -name timeconst.h
```

All these files are generated during the build, in various ways; `timeconst.h` is built by `kernel/time/timeconst.bc`.

`/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/` stores the generated headers (and a few other files) corresponding to the running kernel; the intention is to make them available for external module builds in particular. If you’re building a new kernel, you’ll find the generated files in your build tree (after a kernel build, or an in-tree-module build).